# Docker: How to update your container when your code changes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to use Docker for local development. The problem is that when I make a change to my code, I have to run the following commands to see the updates locally:

```
docker-compose down
docker images # Copy the name of the image
docker rmi <IMAGE_NAME>
docker-compose up -d
```

That's quite a mouthful, and takes a while. (Possibly I could make it into a bash script, but do you think that is a good idea?)

My real question is: Is there a command that I can use (even manually each time) that will update the image & container? Or do I have to go through the ***entire workflow*** above every time I make a change in my code?

Just for reference, here is my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.18.3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: web
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Comment: Try with `docker-compose up -d --build`. It should rebuild all the images on start.

Comment: I believe a bash script is a great way to automate this. If you’re concerned with build times, you can use a combination of docker cp and docker exec to update the code on the go. I recommend checking out VS Code and developing inside the container https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers

Comment: @MarkoE - your solution worked! Can you please put it in a proper answer and I'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Even though there are multiple good answers to this question, I think they missed the point, as the OP is asking about the local dev environment. The command I usually use in this situation is:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

If there aren't any errors in Dockerfile, it should rebuild all the images before bringing up the stack. It could be used in a shell script if needed.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo docker-compose up -d --build
```

If you need to tear down the whole stack, you can have another script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo docker-compose down -v
```

The `-v` flag removes all the volumes so you can have a fresh start.

NOTE: In some cases, `sudo` might not be needed to run the command.

Comment: You're awesome. Thanks for your help in this! They really should have a `docker watch` option, but until I'm smart enough to help build it, I'll reserve my criticisms and use the above. FYI - I had an error that only showed up in the docker container. When I ran in dev locally NOT using Docker, there was no error. So this is a very helpful tool when you need to check.

Comment: No worries, I had similar issues recently with my local dev environment, so if I can help someone resolve their problem faster, it is really my pleasure to help. :)

Comment: Did you ended up using this approach, or sharing volumes? The latter one actually seems easier and faster to reflect the changes to me. Or is there a hidden boulder?

Comment: The main problem I have with this solution is that if you've scaled up a service, this command removes all of them but one.  Of course, you could use `--scale`, but that doesn't help if you've scaled a service temporarily for testing something out.

Answer (score 11):

When a docker image is build the artifacts are already copied and no new change can reflect until you rebuild the image.

But

If it is only for local development, then you can leverage volume sharing to update code inside container in runtime. The idea is to share your app/repo directory on host machine with `/usr/src/app` (as per your Dockerfile) and with this approach your code (and new changes) will be appear on both host and the running container.

Also, you will need to restart the server on every change and for this you can run your app using `nodemon` (as it watches for changes in code and restarts the server)

Changes required in Dockerfile.

```
services:
  web:
    ...
    container_name: web
    ...
    volumes:
      - /path/in/host/machine:/usr/src/app
    ...
    ...
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

Answer (score -4):

You may use `Docker Swarm` as an orchestration tool to apply rolling updates. Check [Apply rolling updates to a service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/rolling-update/).

Basically you issue `docker compose up` once and do it with a shell script maybe, and once you get your containers running and then you may create a `Jenkinsfile` or configure a CI/CD pipeline to pull the updated image and apply it to running container with previous image with `docker service update <NEW_IMAGE>`.

Comment: The question is asking about a local development environment, not a multi-host clustered environment with a dedicated CI system.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I see your point but Can't the user setup this environment in its local machine? I think a Dedicated CI system also isn't required(I have just suggested using `may`) since the user can issue commands manually and even he can configure a CI in its local machine. I have also suggested using scripts.